# Finding perpendicular vector to a given vector and in respect to former position in 3D space

Tags: math, vector, 3d, godot, godot4

I have 3 vectors, xyz, and i want to change only 1 and then calculate the other 2 in respect to their former directions (the closest possible to them). And i want to do it the most efficient way in terms of memory usage/game design.

[small illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MRSL.png)

---

EDIT (after some constructive comments from Stef):

What we have:

- x,y,z 3d vector, normalized and with same origin (0,0,0)
- y' (the up vector changes depending on the surface)

What (i believe) we need:

- z' or x' (and all mutually perpendicular)

What i tried:

- z' with the help of the y - y' angle around the x-axis and vice versa with x' and the z-axis. i think this "could" work with the proper linear algebra knowledge but would still mean an euler rotation, right? i prefer to only rotate with quaternions even though i still earn to figure them out
- using the cross-product of y' and x to get z' and then creating the crossproduct of z' and y' to get x'. in theory it should work? my 3 dot-product are never 0, not one of them

What i desire:

- changing the x and z vector based on the angle of y and y' via a quaternion. i am working in godot and still figuring things out.. that said, i just found this:

> ```
> Quaternion Quaternion ( Vector3 arc_from, Vector3 arc_to )
>
> Constructs a quaternion representing the shortest arc between two points on the surface of a sphere with a radius of 1.0.
> ```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately i's unclear what you want. So you had three vectors called x, y and z. Then vector y is replaced with a new vector y'. And you want to replace z with a new vector z'. That much is clear. The thing that is unclear is: what are your constraints about z'? I assume there is a property that was satisfied by (x, y, z) and which is possibly not satisfied by (x, y', z), so you want to find z' such that (x, y', z') satisfies the property? But what is this property?

Comment: If what you want is for z' to be orthogonal to both x and y', then indeed you can just set z' = crossproduct(x, y'). But apparently you tried that already and that wasn't what you want? You said "I tried multiple things but it felt utterly useless and off point". What does this mean? What things did you try? Did you try the crossproduct? Why did it feel useless?

Comment: (On a side-note: in 3d space, vectors have three coordinates, and in a computer program that handles vectors in 3d space, the three coordinates of a vector `v` are usually denoted `(vx, vy, vz)` or `(x_v, y_v, z_v)` or `v.x, v.y, v.z)` or something similar; in your case this is quickly going to become confusing as you'll have three vectors `x (x.x, x.y, x.z); y (y.x, y.y, y.z) and z (z.x, z.y, z.z)`; and if you write `x_y` it's unclear whether that's coordinate y of vector x or coordinate x of vector y.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Stef! After changing vz to vz', I need vx and vy changed as well so they are all perpendicular to each other (for further quaternion calculcations). When i only change vz it isnt perpendicular to vx or vy anymore. And on top of just finding 2 perpendicular vectors to vz', I need vy' and vx' as close to vy and vx as possible while being perpendicular to vz'.

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused with your notations and with the distinction between a vector, and the coordinates of a vector.

Comment: How about defining your vector z' by first taking the cross product of x and y', let's call w = crossproduct(x, y'), and then finding the vector z' colinear to this cross product that minimises |z' - z|? This can be done with a simple renormalisation, ie `z' = (w.z / ||w||) * (w / ||w||)` (where || || is norm, and `.` is dotproduct)

Comment: I figured my descriptions are not that accurate from what i want to accomplish and i still need to learn to properly articulate. I was talking about vectors, all normalized with the same origin (0,0). But i might be more useful if I update the original post and hopes this clarifies things (for everyone). On the other hand, you mean with norm, the normalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a quaternion that represents the shortest rotation needed to transform a vector into another, so you can apply it your custom basis.

We can start by figuring out the rotation axis for this rotation transformation...

*I'll be writing GDScript. And I'll be assuming the vectors are non-zero and finite.*

```
var axis := arc_from.cross(arc_to)
```

Except that does not work when the vectors are in the same or opposite direction.

If you check the dot product and it says the vectors are in the same direction, then you need no rotation at all. But if the dot product says they are in opposite directions, you need a half turn rotation, yet you need to decide over which axis.

Here is one possible solution:

```
var axis := arc_from.cross(arc_to)
if axis.is_zero_approx():
    var longest_axis := arc_to.max_axis_index()
    var with := Vector3.ONE
    with[longest_axis] = 0.0
    axis = arc_to.cross(with)
```

Here I've created a new `Vector3` that will be `0.0` in the axis that `arc_to` has longest magnitud and `1.0` in the others. So it is guaranteed to not be in the same direction, and then I'm using it do the cross product with `arc_to`, which should give a vector perpendicular to `arc_to`.

This is a way to get a vector perpendicular to an arbitrary vector in 3D space. I remind you that problem has infinite solutions. And this is just one approach.

---

Of course, we should normalize the axis to make sure it is of length `1.0`:

```
var axis := arc_from.cross(arc_to)
if axis.is_zero_approx():
    var longest_axis := arc_to.max_axis_index()
    var with := Vector3.ONE
    with[longest_axis] = 0.0
    axis = arc_to.cross(with)

axis = axis.normalized()
```

Now we can figure out the angle for our rotation:

```
var axis := arc_from.cross(arc_to)
if axis.is_zero_approx():
    var longest_axis := arc_to.max_axis_index()
    var with := Vector3.ONE
    with[longest_axis] = 0.0
    axis = arc_to.cross(with)

axis = axis.normalized()
var angle := arc_from.signed_angle_to(arc_to, axis)
```

And make a quaternion for it:

```
var axis := arc_from.cross(arc_to)
if axis.is_zero_approx():
    var longest_axis := arc_to.max_axis_index()
    var with := Vector3.ONE
    with[longest_axis] = 0.0
    axis = arc_to.cross(with)

axis = axis.normalized()
var angle := arc_from.signed_angle_to(arc_to, axis)
return Quaternion(axis, angle)
```

I believe this is sufficient for your needs.

---

### Addendum

**`is_zero_approx`**

This line is checking if the `axis` vector is approxiately a zero vector:

```
if axis.is_zero_approx():
```

We only care about the case when it is a zero vector, so ideally we could check against zero. But since `axis` is the result of floating point operations we do not have a guarantee that it will be exactly zero.

The check is equivalent to this:

```
if absf(axis.x) < 0.00001 and absf(axis.y) < 0.00001 and absf(axis.z) < 0.00001:
```

---

**`max_axis_index`**

Next, this line give you an index `0`, `1`, or `2` depending which axis is longer `x`, `y`, or `z`:

```
var longest_axis := arc_to.max_axis_index()
```

We can do the same thing like this:

```
var longest_axis := 2
if arc_to.x >= arc_to.y and arc_to.x >= arc_to.z:
    longest_axis = 0
elif arc_to.y >= arc_to.z:
    longest_axis = 1
```

The array access to the `Vector3` allows us to get or set the values by index. So the following will result in a vector with only that axis set to `0.0` and the others to `1.0`:

```
var with := Vector3.ONE
with[longest_axis] = 0.0
```

So we can do this another way:

```
var with := Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
if arc_to.x >= arc_to.y and arc_to.x >= arc_to.z:
    with.x = 0.0
elif arc_to.y >= arc_to.z:
    with.y = 0.0
else:
    with.z = 0.0
```

Or if you prefer:

```
var with := Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
if arc_to.x >= arc_to.y and arc_to.x >= arc_to.z:
    with = Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
elif arc_to.y >= arc_to.z:
    with = Vector3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thx alot! I didn't implement it yet but this is definitely what i was asking for. And thx a second time for this wonderful explanation!

Comment: On a second read I have trouble to fully understand the part in the if function. Could you elaborate a little more what this is doing, especially with is_zero_approx(), max_axis_index() and the with[]?

Comment: @ChrisSchnerr I have expanded the answer with the explanation of that code. I want to reiterate that this just one way to go about it. You may, for example, be interested in getting a rotation axis based on the surrounding to avoid discontinuities, which might be possible to optimize depending on the surface.

Comment: Thx again, you deserve gold! You saved me from aging in triple speed the last weeks, everything worked out fine in terms of the rotation logics..